# Checksum assembly algorithm not adding up to correct value

Tags: string, debugging, assembly, mips, checksum

I'm working on implementing a basic checksum algorithm for an inputted string in MIPS assembly as a general introduction to working in the language, and I could use some error checking.

Here's what I have so far, comments included to keep track of what's happening each step:

```
.data
str1:
    .asciiz "This is a short string."
cs1:
    .word   0x84a
str2:
    .asciiz "This is a much longer string.  In fact, it has two sentences in it, and some funny characters (~`)€."
cs2:
    .word   0x230a
NonSuccessString:
    .asciiz "You have more work to do."
Test1Success:
    .asciiz "Test 1 was successful.  "
Test2Success:
    .asciiz "Test 2 was successful.  "

.text
    la  $a0, str1 #Set $a0 to address of label str1:
    jal checksum #Set $ra to address of next instruction, then jump to label checksum:
    la  $s0, cs1 #Set $s0 to address of label cs1:
    lw  $s1, 0($s0) #Set $s1 to contents of memory address $s0
    beq $v0, $s1, Success1 # If $v0 and $sl are equal, jump to label Success1:
    j NonSuccess # Jump to label NonSuccess:
Success1:
    la  $a0, Test1Success #Set $a0 to address of label Test1Success:
    addi    $v0, $zero, 4 
    syscall
    la  $a0, str2 #Set $a0 to address of label str2:
    jal checksum #Set $ra to return address, then jump to label checksum:
    la  $s0, cs2 #Set $s0 to address of label cs2:
    lw  $s1, 0($s0) #Set $s1 to contents of memory address $s0
    beq $v0, $s1, Success2 # If $v0 and $sl are equal, jump to label Success2:
    j NonSuccess # Jump to label NonSuccess:
Success2:
    la  $a0, Test2Success #Set $a0 to address of label Test2Success:
    addi    $v0, $zero, 4
    syscall
    j Quit # Jump to label Quit:
NonSuccess:
    la  $a0, NonSuccessString #Set $a0 to address of label NonSuccessString:
    addi    $v0, $zero, 4
    syscall
Quit:
    addi    $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall

checksum:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4      # adjust stack for 1 item
        sw   $s0, 0($sp)       # save $s0
    add  $s0, $zero, $zero # i = 0
    L1:
        add $t1, $s0, $a0 # Locate the character at y[i]
        lbu $t2, 0($t1) # Load the unsigned byte value of y[i]
        beq  $t2, $zero, L2    # exit loop if y[i] == 0 
        add $v0, $v0, $t2 # Add the byte to the total value
            addi $s0, $s0, 1  # i = i + 1
        j L1
    L2:
        jr $ra #jump back to $ra
```

The simple string in the first test calculates correctly and I get the first "Test 1 was successful." message, but on the second checksum the debug reports a sum of 0x230e, 4 more than the expected value, meaning something wonky happened. I'm guessing the special characters are probably causing the issue, but I  don't know for sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting `$v0` prior to calculating the checksum. There should be an `add $v0,$zero,$zero` before the `L1:` label.

But I still don't see where the value 0x230a comes from. It seems to me like the correct checksum for the second string is 0x22de.

Comment: 0x230a - 0x22de = 0x002c, which is ',' in ASCII, so maybe you didn't put one of the commas in? Either way, resetting the sum was definitely the problem, looks like everything is working now. Thanks!

Comment: I copied the strings directly from your question. But as long as it's working properly on your side.